# scale videos in p:media tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces

how to scale the video in the media tag?

```
<p:media value="#{mediaBean.media}" width="250" height="225" player="quicktime"/>
```

the resolution is bigger thant 250x225 - so I just see parts of the videoscreen - why it's not automatically scaling the video to 250x225 ? any ideas?

regards

Comment: please post  source of your **`MediaBean`** **`getMedia()`** method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send scale attribute as parameter (f:param) to the player.

```
<p:media value="#{mediaBean.media}" width="250" height="241" player="quicktime"/>
        <f:param name="scale" value="tofit" />
</p:media>
```

Each player specifies what parameters they support.

**In your case quicktime supports scale attribute:**

> **scale**
>
> SCALE is either TOFIT, ASPECT or a number. By default the value of
>   SCALE is 1. If set to TOFIT, the movie is scaled to fit the embedded
>   box as specified by the HEIGHT and WIDTH attributes. If this is set to
>   ASPECT, the movie will scale to fit the embedded box while maintaining
>   the aspect ratio. If this is set with a number, the movie will be
>   scaled by that number (e.g. 1.5). Note: Using the number scale
>   attribute with a QTVR Panorama movie can degrade the performance of
>   the movie even on high-end systems.

**Useful links here:**

[Quicktime](http://library.creativecow.net/articles/chaffin_abraham/embedding-quicktime-movies.php)

[Flash](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)

[Windows Media Player](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_playerref.asp)

Comment: HI, I added the following lines, but not working. I am using -3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, - btw. I am playing the .3gp - 640x480 format, thx

Comment: please improve your question, post source of your **`MediaBean`** **`getMedia()`** method and generated html.

Comment: sorry i forget it. you should also use **scale** attribute to scale the movie according to your needs. **SCALE is either TOFIT, ASPECT or a number.**

Comment: okay thx - will check it on monday when I have access...getMedia() I am not using...

Comment: thx - works perfect with: <f:param name="scale" value="tofit" />